# Setup Saxon to run in windows server 2008

Tags: asp-classic, xslt-2.0, windows-server-2008, saxon

The problem I have is that the Windows operating system does not support XSLT 2 which we have wrote our application with just to find that it's not supported.

I was able to successfully compile XSL and XML file to output HTML file locally and it works but I need this to happen on the server.

I have a classic asp file that gets data from API and then we have XSL file that dictates the style but need it to run straight when the page in the browser and show new results with no need to recompile the file manually.

I have windows 2008 server with IIS 6 and can't find sample code anywhere.

Comment: Do you expect to be able to run Saxon 9 from classic ASP code (i.e. VBScript, JScript)? Do you use the Java version of Saxon 9 or the .NET version when you say "I was able to successfully compile XSL and XML file to output HTML file locally and it works but I need this to happen on the server"? Does the Windows server 2008 allow you to install the Java JRE or does it have .NET framework 4?

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your reply. Yes, I am trying to run saxon 9 from asp classic(VBScript). I use .NET version on 2008 server and by successfully compiled I meant that I was able to run the script via cli which outputted html file but now I need it to join it inside the code so whenever xml file updated(or on each call transform the file and output html or asp file to be included in the website)

Comment: Can you show us your existing "script" you "run via cli"? Are you just calling Saxon's `Transform.exe` from the command line? Do you want to do that with VBScript? Seems more like a VBScript/ASP programming problem so you might want to add a tag for that.

Comment: I have only ran the following. bin\Transform -t -s:cruiseBanners.xml -xsl:cruiseBanners.xsl -o:c:\inc.html adding an asp classic tag now

Comment: What does "I have a classic asp file that gets data from API" mean exactly, in what form does your classic ASP code receive the data, as a  VBScript string with the XML document?